# How to get the slug to show up in graphql using NetlifyCMS and Gatsby?

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

When adding netlify cms to a site how does one go about getting the slug to show up in graphql? 
I have one collection for a blog post and everything shows up except the slug:

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master # Branch to update (optional; defaults to master)

media_folder: static/images
public_folder: /images

collections:
  - name: "blog"
  label: "Blog"
  folder: "content/blogPost"
  create: true
  slug: "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}-{{slug}}"
  fields: # The fields for each document, usually in front matter
    - { label: "Layout", name: "layout", widget: "hidden", default: "blog" }
    - { label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string" }
    - { label: "Publish Date", name: "date", widget: "datetime" }
    - { label: "Featured Image", name: "thumbnail", widget: "image" }
    - { label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown" }
```

And here is my graphql query: 
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `slug` in the GraphQL query is **not** part of the frontmatter of the fields in the `config.yml`. These slug fields are not related. The one you are referring to in your query is from the node in Gatsby.

The `fields` value in the GraphQL query above is missing from your `node`. This would have to be passed using the `gatsby-node.js` config by adding it as in this example:

```
const { createFilePath } = require('gatsby-source-filesystem')

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, boundActionCreators, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = boundActionCreators

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped me too. Thank you!

Comment: For anyone like me who read this answer and didn't understand it, it helps to compare with the full `gastby-node.js` file from the [starter project](https://github.com/erquhart/gatsby-netlify-cms-example).